# Eclipse plugin Development- How to remove search again menu item from search result page

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am new to eclipse plugin development.
I am creating a separate search for my project.
I have already added a new search page to existing search dialog and even getting the results in the search page.
But I am struggling to access get the search again menu to work .It always remain disabled I am not able to remove it nor able to enable it.

I am working on eclipse kepler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This menu item cannot be removed.

The enablement of the item is controlled by your `ISearchQuery.canRerun()` method.